# Is this QML valid (binding twice to a property)?

Tags: qt, animation, qml

Because it keeps exhibiting strange behavior (and crashing QMLViewer).

The code:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 800; height: 600

    Rectangle {
        width: 60; height: 60
        x: rect1.x - 5; y: rect1.y - 5
        color: "green"

        property NumberAnimation anim: NumberAnimation { 
            id: animId; duration: 2000 
        }

        Behavior on x {
            animation: animId
        }
        Behavior on y {
            animation: animId
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        width: 50; height: 50
        color: "red"
    }

    focus: true

    Keys.onRightPressed: rect1.x = rect1.x + 100
    Keys.onLeftPressed:  rect1.x = rect1.x - 100
    Keys.onUpPressed:    rect1.y = rect1.y - 100
    Keys.onDownPressed:  rect1.y = rect1.y + 100
}
```

Note the `anim` property, whose value is obviously not a child of the enclosing element.

This possibly brings us to a question of QML memory management and ownership (again).

Comment: Note: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html#sharing-animation-instances seems to prohibit his in Qt5

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't looks like QML `Behavior` element can share it's `animation` instance with others. If you define `NumberAnimation` for each `Behavior` it should work properly.

```
Rectangle {
    width: 60; height: 60
    x: rect1.x - 5; y: rect1.y - 5
    color: "green"

    Behavior on x {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 2000
        }
    }
    Behavior on y {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 2000
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, ok (possibly), but based on what can we state that? I.e., can you hint me to somewhere within the Qt docs, where this matter is explicitly dealt with?

Comment: This is based on http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeanimation.html, section "Default Animation as Behaviors, where on animation is bound by id to another one.

Comment: I see that this default-animation-as-behaviors example have same problem as in your case. It works only if properties changed synchronously (wait for animation to finish before starting new one).